# The id I set in Google Sites for an image doesn't work

Tags: html, google-sites

Every time I try to add an id to an image in my html script, for my google site, and save the changes it disappears from the html script. Here is an example of what I want:

```html
<div style="text-align:left;display:block;margin-right:auto;margin-left:auto">
<table cellspacing="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="background-color:rgb(243,243,243);width:320px;height:131px">&nbsp;Welcome!<br>
<hr style="color:#f3f3f3;background-color:#00b0f0;height:2px;width:100%">
<ol><li>Introduction</li>
<li>Contacts &amp; Their Roles</li>
<li>Regular Tasks &amp; Deadlines</li>
<li>Priorities/Initiatives of 2017</li>
<li><a href="https://sites.google.com/">AMERA Finance &amp; Accounting Guidelines</a></li>
</ol>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
<div style="text-align:left;display:block;margin-right:auto;margin-left:auto"><br>
</div>
<div style="text-align:left;display:block;margin-right:auto;margin-left:auto"><img id="intro" border="0" src="https://sites.google.com/imagelink" style="display:block;margin-right:auto;margin-left:auto;text-align:center"></div>
<div style="text-align:left;display:block;margin-right:auto;margin-left:auto">
<div style="text-align:center"><br>
</div>
<img id="contacts" border="0" src="https://sites.google.com/imagelink" style="display:block;margin-right:auto;margin-left:auto;text-align:center">
<div></div>
<br>
<div style="text-align:left;display:block;margin-right:auto;margin-left:auto"></div>
<div style="text-align:left;display:block;margin-right:auto;margin-left:auto">
<div style="text-align:center"></div>
<div style="text-align:center">
<div style="text-align:left">
<img id="tasks" border="0" src="https://sites.google.com/imagelink" style="display:block;margin-right:auto;margin-left:auto;text-align:center"></div>
<div style="text-align:left"><br>
</div>
</div>
<img id="initiatives" border="0" src="https://sites.google.com/imagelink" style="display:block;margin-right:auto;margin-left:auto;text-align:center">
<br>
</div>
<br>
<div><br>
</div>
</div>
```

The issue is that when I enter that into my html script it comes out as this:

```html
<div style="text-align:left;display:block;margin-right:auto;margin-left:auto">
<table cellspacing="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="background-color:rgb(243,243,243);width:320px;height:131px">&nbsp;Welcome!<br>
<hr style="color:#f3f3f3;background-color:#00b0f0;height:2px;width:100%">
<ol><li>Introduction</li>
<li>Contacts &amp; Their Roles</li>
<li>Regular Tasks &amp; Deadlines</li>
<li>Priorities/Initiatives of 2017</li>
<li><a href="https://sites.google.com">AMERA Finance &amp; Accounting Guidelines</a></li>
</ol>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
<div style="text-align:left;display:block;margin-right:auto;margin-left:auto"><br>
</div>
<div style="text-align:left;display:block;margin-right:auto;margin-left:auto"><img border="0" src="https://sites.google.com/imagelink" style="display:block;margin-right:auto;margin-left:auto;text-align:center"></div>
<div style="text-align:left;display:block;margin-right:auto;margin-left:auto">
<div style="text-align:center"><br>
</div>
<img border="0" src="https://sites.google.com/imagelink" style="display:block;margin-right:auto;margin-left:auto;text-align:center">
<div></div>
<br>
<div style="text-align:left;display:block;margin-right:auto;margin-left:auto"></div>
<div style="text-align:left;display:block;margin-right:auto;margin-left:auto">
<div style="text-align:center"></div>
<div style="text-align:center">
<div style="text-align:left">
<img border="0" src="https://sites.google.com/imagelink" style="display:block;margin-right:auto;margin-left:auto;text-align:center"></div>
<div style="text-align:left"><br>
</div>
</div>
<img border="0" src="https://sites.google.com/imagelink" style="display:block;margin-right:auto;margin-left:auto;text-align:center">
<br>
</div>
<br>
<div><br>
</div>
</div>
```

I don't know why it does this, I am probably making a basic mistake and could really use any help!

Comment: What do you mean by disappears? From what? Is it disappearing in your developer tools that you use in the browser?  I'm not sure if you didn't post all your HTML code or you are actually missing <div> tags, but there seems to be some missing. I also recommend putting spaces in between each style attribute, makes your code a little easier to read.

Comment: I have updated the HTML code, I provided the whole section, hope this helps. What happens is that I write the first code and when I save the code in the site it becomes the second one. For some reason all the id="idname" get removed by the system and they are not there when I open the code with the developer tool. I am very confused because I can't find the reason why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the issue with the help of a friend. To solve this issue you just add a section before your `<img>` with `<a name="anchorname"></a>`. As an id="anchorname" doesn't work in Google Sites.

Then you just need to make the hyperlink for this section be https://sitename.com/pagename#anchorname

Hope this helps anybody needing the answer to my previous question.